Retaining Original List Element Names in Loop-Based Function Application in R
I'm encountering an issue with preserving the original names of list elements when applying a function within a loop in R. Specifically, I have a function that relies on both the value and the name of the list element. While calling the function directly yields the desired results, using it within a loop (e.g., with lapply) leads to loss of the original element names. How can I ensure that the function retains the correct names of the list elements when applied in a loop?
This first part of the question includes a
Minimal reprex
# function definition

test_function <- 
    \(x) {
        list(deparse(substitute(x)),
             x)
    }

# minimal example input

arg_name <- "value"

test_function(arg_name)

[[1]]
[1] "arg_name"

[[2]]
[1] "value"

I need to loop-apply the function to a list:
# example list

my_list <- list(element_1 = arg_name, element_2 = arg_name))

lapply(my_list, test_function)

i expected lapply(...)  to return:
[
$element_1
$element_1[[1]]
[1] "element_1"

$element_1[[2]]
[1] "value"


$element_2
$element_2[[1]]
[1] "element_2"

$element_2[[2]]
[1] "value"

But I am getting this instead:

$element_1
$element_1[[1]]
[1] "X[[i]]"

$element_1[[2]]
[1] "value"


$element_2
$element_2[[1]]
[1] "X[[i]]"

$element_2[[2]]
[1] "value"


I suspect lapply passes its elements without their original names to its FUN argument, the elements are renamed internally, and the FUN call is similar to (but not quite equal to) this:
`X[[i]]` <- X[[i]]
FUN(`X[[i]]`)

Is there a way to use the actual names of the input list elements without losing the information inside looping functions?
Actual scenario
The actual problem I am working on is a bit more complex, and it is datailed bellow, although the reprex above should reproduce the issue.
data
list_of_2x2_tables <- list(
    Arthritis = with(vcd::Arthritis, table(Sex, improved = Improved != "None")),
    Toothgrowth = with(ToothGrowth, table(supp, dose = dose >= 1)))

individual_table_from_the_Global_env <-
    list_of_2x2_tables[[1]]

function
compare_chisq_tests <- function(x) {

    # dataset_name
    dataset <- deparse(substitute(x))
    
    # extract dimnames to use as scores argument downstream
    names <- names(dimnames(x))
    
    # transform scores into proper named list of sequences
    scores_argument <-
        list()
    for (i in names) {
        scores_argument[[i]] <- 1:2
    }
    
    # create two chisq_test objects, one base chisq, the other with ordered elements
    a <- coin::chisq_test(x)
    b <- coin::chisq_test(x, scores = scores_argument)
    output <- dplyr::tibble(
        dataset = rep(dataset,
                      2),
        test = c(slot(a, "method"),
                 slot(b, "method")),
        p.value = c(coin::pvalue(a),
                    coin::pvalue(b))
    )
    output
}

expected output
#with single element
compare_chisq_tests(individual_table_from_the_Global_env)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  dataset                              test                              p.value
  <chr>                                <chr>                               <dbl>
1 individual_table_from_the_Global_env Pearson Chi-Squared Test                1
2 individual_table_from_the_Global_env Linear-by-Linear Association Test       1

# with lapply
lapply(list_of_2x2_tables, compare_chisq_tests)

$Arthritis
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  dataset    test                              p.value
  <chr>      <chr>                               <dbl>
1 Arthritis  Pearson Chi-Squared Test           0.0317
2 Arthritis  Linear-by-Linear Association Test  0.0317

$Toothgrowth
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  dataset      test                              p.value
  <chr>        <chr>                               <dbl>
1 Toothgrowth  Pearson Chi-Squared Test                1
2 Toothgrowth  Linear-by-Linear Association Test       1

# see that the variable `dataset` reflects the name of the dataset used in the iteration

Actual output
$Arthritis
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  dataset test                              p.value
  <chr>   <chr>                               <dbl>
1 X[[i]]  Pearson Chi-Squared Test           0.0317
2 X[[i]]  Linear-by-Linear Association Test  0.0317

$Toothgrowth
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  dataset test                              p.value
  <chr>   <chr>                               <dbl>
1 X[[i]]  Pearson Chi-Squared Test                1
2 X[[i]]  Linear-by-Linear Association Test       1

# `dataset` is always the constant `X[[1]]`.


The deparse(substitute(..)) is keying off of what it was called as, which is based on how lapply calls it not how you call it. Within lapply, it iterates over its vector/list argument that it knows as X, and internally (using .Internal(lapply(..))) it calls the the anon-func inside a loop, likely something like for (i in seq_along(X)) fun(X[[i]]) and captures the results into a list. (I haven't look into the .Internal code for lapply yet, I imagine that is what it is doing, especially given what you find here.)

This is the case even if you use tibble::lst that, similar to base::data.frame, defaults to naming unnamed arguments based on their object (deparse/subst) name. I suggest that if you need both the name and the value to be evaluated, do not try to rely on deparse(substitute(..)), that path leads to madness (as you can tell).

Thoughts: (1) Can your function accept both the value and its name? With that, use Map(test_function, obj, names(obj)). (2) Can you inject the name after-the-fact? Not dissimilar from my #1, you could follow lapply(.., test_function) with |> Map(names(obj), list) or similar.

A perhaps unwise route around your problem would be iterating over a list of names, like c("arg_name", "arg_name"), and then having your function be something like list(x, get(x)).

I just made some EXTENSIVE EDITS, hopping the question gets re-opened. Should anyone still think it is below SO standards, please leave a comment??

@GuedesBF Looks better now, I have reopened the question.

Some thoughts.
If we start with a named list,
obj <- setNames(list(arg_name, arg_name), c("arg_name", "arg_name"))
obj
# $arg_name
# [1] "value"
# $arg_name
# [1] "value"

then we can use Map instead of lapply with a two-arg function:
test_function <- \(x, nm) { list(nm, x) }
Map(test_function, obj, names(obj))
# $arg_name
# $arg_name[[1]]
# [1] "arg_name"
# $arg_name[[2]]
# [1] "value"
# $arg_name
# $arg_name[[1]]
# [1] "arg_name"
# $arg_name[[2]]
# [1] "value"

purrr::imap(obj, ~ test_function(.x, .y))
### same output

(you can unname(..) if you don't want the top-level names).
Or ... you can keep the 1-arg function and apply the names after-the-fact:
test_function <- \(x) { list(x); }
lapply(obj, test_function) |>
  Map(names(obj), f = c)
# $arg_name
# $arg_name[[1]]
# [1] "value"
# $arg_name[[2]]
# [1] "arg_name"
# $arg_name
# $arg_name[[1]]
# [1] "value"
# $arg_name[[2]]
# [1] "arg_name"

(albeit reversed, easily fixed with a trivial wrapper around my naive c).

You can define the function with an optional name to make the simple case easer test_function <- \(x, nm=deparse(substitute(x))) { list(nm, x) } and mget(c("arg_name", "arg_name")) is a bit quicker to generate the self-named list.

Yes, nm=deparse(..) makes the function a little easier for interactive use, though it doesn't really resolve the issue of using it within lapply and family. I agree that mget works better there, but then again these values and names are a bit contrived anyway so I wonder what the "real" data looks like. Thanks MrFlick!

The real data is just a list of datasets. The function processes the dataset, and returns a one-row tibble. One of the columns in the tibble should contain the dataset name.
An example input: mtcars. Example output: tibble(dataset = 'mtcars', col_1 = mtcars[1,1]). I intended to call the function over a list of datasets and finally purrr::list_r_bind them.

If you are strictly confined to using base R or if you need the specific structure you lay out (lapply a function of a list) then I can delete this.
If not you could consider using some rlang tools to quote arguments you pass through ... and then evaluate them in a quasiquotation function like so:
library(rlang)

f <- function(...) {
  lquo <- enquos(...)
  
  test_function <- \(x) list(as_name(get_expr(x)), eval_tidy(x))
  lapply(lquo, test_function)
}

In this instance, the call would be a bit different (instead of as a list):
f(arg_name, arg_name)
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "arg_name"
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] "value"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "arg_name"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "value"

So instead, you would be iterating over a list of quosures that have captured the expression and their environments.

Otherwise, as suggested in the comments by @Brian you could use the vectorized version mget which would get you a named list that you can manipulate further. Again the function call is slightly different than what you have specified:
test_function <- function(x) {
  y <- mget(unlist(x), envir = parent.frame())
  lapply(seq_along(y), \(i) list(names(y)[[i]], y[[i]]))
}

test_function(list('arg_name', 'arg_name'))


Now that you have made a rough statement about what your goal is, maybe you want:
> o1 <- list("mtcars1", "iris1", 'ChickWeight1')
> 
> lapply(o1, \(x) data.frame(dataset=x, col_1=get(x)[1, 1])) |> do.call(w='rbind')
       dataset col_1
1      mtcars1  21.0
2        iris1   5.1
3 ChickWeight1  42.0

or
> test_fun1 <- \(x) data.frame(dataset=x, col_1=get(x)[1, 1])
> lapply(o1, test_fun1) |> do.call(w='rbind')
       dataset col_1
1      mtcars1  21.0
2        iris1   5.1
3 ChickWeight1  42.0

or "vectorized"
> o2 <- c('mtcars1', 'iris1', 'ChickWeight1')
> test_fun2 <- \(x) data.frame(dataset=x, col_1=sapply(mget(x, parent.frame()), `[`, i=1, j=1))
> test_fun2(o2) 
                  dataset col_1
mtcars1           mtcars1  21.0
iris1               iris1   5.1
ChickWeight1 ChickWeight1  42.0


Data:
To address lazy evaluation.
> mtcars1 <- mtcars; iris1 <- iris; ChickWeight1 <- ChickWeight


That is nice, but you are first assigning the data to the global env, then geting the values from the global env, whereas i expect to get those from inside a list

@GuedesBF Not really, datasets that come with R aren't available until evaluated (lazy evaluation). Not sure where you got your list. Please make your question clearer.

When you type ?lapply in the console, you will see the following description in the Note section

For historical reasons, the calls created by lapply are unevaluated,
and code has been written (e.g., bquote) that relies on this. This
means that the recorded call is always of the form FUN(X[[i]], ...),
with i replaced by the current (integer or double) index. This is not
normally a problem, but it can be if FUN uses sys.call or match.call
or if it is a primitive function that makes use of the call. This
means that it is often safer to call primitive functions with a
wrapper, so that e.g. lapply(ll, function(x) is.numeric(x)) is
required to ensure that method dispatch for is.numeric occurs
correctly.


It's not necessarily lapply specific; o <- list(arg_name, arg_name); r <- vector('list', length(o)); for (i in seq_along(o)) r[[i]] <- test_function(o[[i]]); r.

@jay.sf it will give "o[[i]]" instead of "arg_name" in the output r

Yes,  I meant it's the same with for, i.e. not using lapply.
